# What is the main difference between implicit and explicit case analysis?

Tags: rust

While reading the [chapter on error handling in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#working-with-multiple-error-types), I wondered what the opposite of the often-mentioned "explicit case analysis" would be. I know and understand that this code sample uses explicit case analysis:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    match *self {
        CliError::Io(ref err) => write!(f, "IO error: {}", err),
        CliError::Parse(ref err) => write!(f, "Parse error: {}", err),
    }
}
```

But what is implicit case analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the book, **case analysis** means performing a computation by directly analyzing each case of an `enum`, such as using the `match` or `if let` expression. An extreme example given from the book is

```
fn file_path_ext_explicit(file_path: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    match file_name(file_path) {    // <-- case analysis
        None => None,
        Some(name) => match extension(name) {   // <-- another case analysis
            None => None,
            Some(ext) => Some(ext),
        }
    }
}
```

**Explicit case analysis** just means using "case analysis" explicitly.

There is no "implicit case analysis". The book suggests to *abstract away* commonly used case-analysis patterns into composable methods or macros, perhaps that's what you're thinking of.

For instance, we could hide the case-analysis (`match` expression) in an `and_then` method on `Option<T>`:

```
fn and_then<F, T, A>(option: Option<T>, f: F) -> Option<A>
        where F: FnOnce(T) -> Option<A> {
    match option {   // <-- case analysis moved into here
        None => None,
        Some(value) => f(value),
    }
}
```

the `file_path_ext_explicit` function could then be simplified to

```
fn file_path_ext(file_path: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    // no `match` expressions
    file_name(file_path).and_then(extension)
}
```

which expresses the intent of the function more clearly and less prone to logical mistakes.